# Unable to validate signature of JWT token generated using .NetCore in a Java springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, .net-core, jwt

We've generated a Bearer JWT token in .NET Core and have signed the token using the pfx of a X509 self signed certificate generated using Powershell.

We need to verify the token signature in a Springboot Java application.
To achieve this we have imported the pfx into a java keystore (jks) using the key tool in Java.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "certificate.pfx" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore "clientcert.jks" -deststoretype JKS
```

We're doing the verification of the token signature in a Resource Server in which we have a JwtAccessTokenConverter configured as below.

```
JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
InputStream inJksStream = null;
InputStream inputJksStream = null;
inJksStream = new FileInputStream("clientcert.jks");
inputJksStream = new BufferedInputStream(inJksStream);
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");         
trustStore.load(inputJksStream, "password".toCharArray());
Key trustStorePrivateKey = trustStore.getKey("alias-value", "password".toCharArray());
converter.setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(trustStorePrivateKey.getEncoded()));
```

The Controller in the application is decorated with the following element.
`@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`

However we encounter a signature invalid exception when a valid JWT token is passed along with a request to the Springboot application.

Is this the appropriate way to verify a Bearer JWT token in Springboot?

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt a similar issue when issuing a JWT using IdentiyServer4.  I may be able to help if I can see the output of your error.

Comment: I recieve `unable verify the first certificate` with 500 status code when using postman. in chrome just 500 status code with nothing in response

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using the auth0 library to verify your JWT. I just implemented this in a project and it was a lot easier and involved a lot less code than other libraries.

maven: com.auth0 / java-jwt / 3.0.1

A simple method to verify your JWT can be found below...

```
public static DecodedJWT decodeJWT(String jwtString) {
    try {
        String secret = //get your secret key
        return JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(secret))
                .withIssuer("foo")
                .build()
                .verify(jwtString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```